# Why does pdoc in pre-commit pass locally, but fail with "files were modified by this hook" in GitHub action?

Tags: python, github, pre-commit, pre-commit.com, pdoc

Pdoc is invoked last in my pre-commit hook, it builds documentation to `/docs`, which is included in my repository. Files in `/docs` are excluded from the pre-commit hook, so the formatting hooks don't touch them.

I observe the following pattern:

1. I run the pre-commit locally using `pre-commit run --all`. The hook passes.
2. I push my commit to the corresponding GitHub repository, where an action is triggered that runs the pre-commit automatically. The hook fails with the message that "files were modified by this hook".

My `.pre-commit-config.yaml` looks like this:

```
exclude: "docs/"
repos:
  - repo: local
    hooks:
    -   id: pdoc
        name: pdoc
        description: 'pdoc: Auto-generate API documentation for Python projects'
        entry: pdoc -o ./docs -t ./misc/pdoc-template ./my_pkg
        language: python
        language_version: python3
        require_serial: true
        types: [python]
```

My `.github/workflows/pre-commit.yml` that defines the GitHub action looks like this:

```
name: pre-commit

on:
  push:
    branches: [main, develop]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main, develop]

jobs:
  pre-commit:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 10

    steps:
      - name: Check out repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v3
        with:
          python-version: "3.10"

      - name: Install my pkg
        run: |
          pip install .[dev]
          pip list

      - name: Run pre-commit
        run: pre-commit run -a
```

Using Pdoc's `--show-diff-on-failure` option in the GitHub action suggests that `search.js` has different content. This is the full diff:

```
2022-06-19T15:22:18.3695089Z All changes made by hooks:
2022-06-19T15:22:18.3723729Z diff --git a/docs/search.js b/docs/search.js
2022-06-19T15:22:18.3724366Z index 0bbe6a8..82690ba 100644
2022-06-19T15:22:18.3725479Z --- a/docs/search.js
2022-06-19T15:22:18.3725832Z +++ b/docs/search.js
2022-06-19T15:22:18.3726181Z @@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
2022-06-19T15:22:18.3726460Z  window.pdocSearch = (function(){
2022-06-19T15:22:18.3823408Z  /** elasticlunr - http://weixsong.github.io * Copyright (C) 2017 Oliver Nightingale * Copyright (C) 2017 Wei Song * MIT Licensed */!function(){function e(e){if(null===e||"object"!=typeof e)return e;var t=e.constructor();for(var n in e)e.hasOwnProperty(n)&&(t[n]=e[n]);return t}var t=function(e){var n=new t.Index;return n.pipeline.add(t.trimmer,t.stopWordFilter,t.stemmer),e&&e.call(n,n),n};t.version="0.9.5",lunr=t,t.utils={},t.utils.warn=function(e){return function(t){e.console&&console.warn&&console.warn(t)}}(this),t.utils.toString=function(e){return void 0===e||null===e?"":e.toString()},t.EventEmitter=function(){this.events={}},t.EventEmitter.prototype.addListener=function(){var e=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),t=e.pop(),n=e;if("function"!=typeof t)throw new TypeError("last argument must be a function");n.forEach(function(e){this.hasHandler(e)||(this.events[e]=[]),this.events[e].push(t)},this)},t.EventEmitter.prototype.removeListener=function(e,t){if(this.hasHandler(e)){var n=this.events[e].indexOf(t);-1!==n&&(this.events[e].splice(n,1),0==this.events[e].length&&delete this.events[e])}},t.EventEmitter.prototype.emit=function(e){if(this.hasHandler(e)){var t=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);this.events[e].forEach(function(e){e.apply(void 0,t)},this)}},t.EventEmitter.prototype.hasHandler=function(e){return e in this.events},t.tokenizer=function(e){if(!arguments.length||null===e||void 0===e)return[];if(Array.isArray(e)){var n=e.filter(function(e){return null===e||void 0===e?!1:!0});n=n.map(function(e){return t.utils.toString(e).toLowerCase()});var i=[];return n.forEach(function(e){var n=e.split(t.tokenizer.seperator);i=i.concat(n)},this),i}return e.toString().trim().toLowerCase().split(t.tokenizer.seperator)},t.tokenizer.defaultSeperator=/[\s\-]+/,t.tokenizer.seperator=t.tokenizer.defaultSeperator,t.tokenizer.setSeperator=function(e){null!==e&&void 0!==e&&"object"==typeof e&&(t.tokenizer.seperator=e)},t.tokenizer.resetSeperator=function(){t.tokenizer.seperator=t.tokenizer.defaultSeperator},t.tokenizer.getSeperator=function(){return t.tokenizer.seperator},t.Pipeline=function(){this._queue=[]},t.Pipeline.registeredFunctions={},t.Pipeline.registerFunction=function(e,n){n in t.Pipeline.registeredFunctions&&t.utils.warn("Overwriting existing registered function: "+n),e.label=n,t.Pipeline.registeredFunctions[n]=e},t.Pipeline.getRegisteredFunction=function(e){return e in t.Pipeline.registeredFunctions!=!0?null:t.Pipeline.registeredFunctions[e]},t.Pipeline.warnIfFunctionNotRegistered=function(e){var n=e.label&&e.label in this.registeredFunctions;n||t.utils.warn("Function is not registered with pipeline. This may cause problems when serialising the index.\n",e)},t.Pipeline.load=function(e){var n=new t.Pipeline;return e.forEach(function(e){var i=t.Pipeline.getRegisteredFunction(e);if(!i)throw new Error("Cannot load un-registered function: "+e);n.add(i)}),n},t.Pipeline.prototype.add=function(){var e=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);e.forEach(function(e){t.Pipeline.warnIfFunctionNotRegistered(e),this._queue.push(e)},this)},t.Pipeline.prototype.after=function(e,n){t.Pipeline.warnIfFunctionNotRegistered(n);var i=this._queue.indexOf(e);if(-1===i)throw new Error("Cannot find existingFn");this._queue.splice(i+1,0,n)},t.Pipeline.prototype.before=function(e,n){t.Pipeline.warnIfFunctionNotRegistered(n);var i=this._queue.indexOf(e);if(-1===i)throw new Error("Cannot find existingFn");this._queue.splice(i,0,n)},t.Pipeline.prototype.remove=function(e){var t=this._queue.indexOf(e);-1!==t&&this._queue.splice(t,1)},t.Pipeline.prototype.run=function(e){for(var t=[],n=e.length,i=this._queue.length,o=0;n>o;o++){for(var r=e[o],s=0;i>s&&(r=this._queue[s](r,o,e),void 0!==r&&null!==r);s++);void 0!==r&&null!==r&&t.push(r)}return t},t.Pipeline.prototype.reset=function(){this._queue=[]},t.Pipeline.prototype.get=function(){return this._queue},t.Pipeline.prototype.toJSON=function(){return this._queue.map(function(e){return t.Pipeline.warnIfFunctionNotRegistered(e),e.label})},t.Index=function(){this._fields=[],this._ref="id",this.pipeline=new t.Pipeline,this.documentStore=new t.DocumentStore,this.index={},this.eventEmitter=new t.EventEmitter,this._idfCache={},this.on("add","remove","update",function(){this._idfCache={}}.bind(this))},t.Index.prototype.on=function(){var e=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);return this.eventEmitter.addListener.apply(this.eventEmitter,e)},t.Index.prototype.off=function(e,t){return this.eventEmitter.removeListener(e,t)},t.Index.load=function(e){e.version!==t.version&&t.utils.warn("version mismatch: current "+t.version+" importing "+e.version);var n=new this;n._fields=e.fields,n._ref=e.ref,n.documentStore=t.DocumentStore.load(e.documentStore),n.pipeline=t.Pipeline.load(e.pipeline),n.index={};for(var i in e.index)n.index[i]=t.InvertedIndex.load(e.index[i]);return n},t.Index.prototype.addField=function(e){return this._fields.push(e),this.index[e]=new t.InvertedIndex,this},t.Index.prototype.setRef=function(e){return this._ref=e,this},t.Index.prototype.saveDocument=function(e){return this.documentStore=new t.DocumentStore(e),this},t.Index.prototype.addDoc=function(e,n){if(e){var n=void 0===n?!0:n,i=e[this._ref];this.documentStore.addDoc(i,e),this._fields.forEach(function(n){var o=this.pipeline.run(t.tokenizer(e[n]));this.documentStore.addFieldLength(i,n,o.length);var r={};o.forEach(function(e){e in r?r[e]+=1:r[e]=1},this);for(var s in r){var u=r[s];u=Math.sqrt(u),this.index[n].addToken(s,{ref:i,tf:u})}},this),n&&this.eventEmitter.emit("add",e,this)}},t.Index.prototype.removeDocByRef=function(e){if(e&&this.documentStore.isDocStored()!==!1&&this.documentStore.hasDoc(e)){var t=this.documentStore.getDoc(e);this.removeDoc(t,!1)}},t.Index.prototype.removeDoc=function(e,n){if(e){var n=void 0===n?!0:n,i=e[this._ref];this.documentStore.hasDoc(i)&&(this.documentStore.removeDoc(i),this._fields.forEach(function(n){var o=this.pipeline.run(t.tokenizer(e[n]));o.forEach(function(e){this.index[n].removeToken(e,i)},this)},this),n&&this.eventEmitter.emit("remove",e,this))}},t.Index.prototype.updateDoc=function(e,t){var t=void 0===t?!0:t;this.removeDocByRef(e[this._ref],!1),this.addDoc(e,!1),t&&this.eventEmitter.emit("update",e,this)},t.Index.prototype.idf=function(e,t){var n="@"+t+"/"+e;if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this._idfCache,n))return this._idfCache[n];var i=this.index[t].getDocFreq(e),o=1+Math.log(this.documentStore.length/(i+1));return this._idfCache[n]=o,o},t.Index.prototype.getFields=function(){return this._fields.slice()},t.Index.prototype.search=function(e,n){if(!e)return[];e="string"==typeof e?{any:e}:JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e));var i=null;null!=n&&(i=JSON.stringify(n));for(var o=new t.Configuration(i,this.getFields()).get(),r={},s=Object.keys(e),u=0;u<s.length;u++){var a=s[u];r[a]=this.pipeline.run(t.tokenizer(e[a]))}var l={};for(var c in o){var d=r[c]||r.any;if(d){var f=this.fieldSearch(d,c,o),h=o[c].boost;for(var p in f)f[p]=f[p]*h;for(var p in f)p in l?l[p]+=f[p]:l[p]=f[p]}}var v,g=[];for(var p in l)v={ref:p,score:l[p]},this.documentStore.hasDoc(p)&&(v.doc=this.documentStore.getDoc(p)),g.push(v);return g.sort(function(e,t){return t.score-e.score}),g},t.Index.prototype.fieldSearch=function(e,t,n){var i=n[t].bool,o=n[t].expand,r=n[t].boost,s=null,u={};return 0!==r?(e.forEach(function(e){var n=[e];1==o&&(n=this.index[t].expandToken(e));var r={};n.forEach(function(n){var o=this.index[t].getDocs(n),a=this.idf(n,t);if(s&&"AND"==i){var l={};for(var c in s)c in o&&(l[c]=o[c]);o=l}n==e&&this.fieldSearchStats(u,n,o);for(var c in o){var d=this.index[t].getTermFrequency(n,c),f=this.documentStore.getFieldLength(c,t),h=1;0!=f&&(h=1/Math.sqrt(f));var p=1;n!=e&&(p=.15*(1-(n.length-e.length)/n.length));var v=d*a*h*p;c in r?r[c]+=v:r[c]=v}},this),s=this.mergeScores(s,r,i)},this),s=this.coordNorm(s,u,e.length)):void 0},t.Index.prototype.mergeScores=function(e,t,n){if(!e)return t;if("AND"==n){var i={};for(var o in t)o in e&&(i[o]=e[o]+t[o]);return i}for(var o in t)o in e?e[o]+=t[o]:e[o]=t[o];return e},t.Index.prototype.fieldSearchStats=function(e,t,n){for(var i in n)i in e?e[i].push(t):e[i]=[t]},t.Index.prototype.coordNorm=function(e,t,n){for(var i in e)if(i in t){var o=t[i].length;e[i]=e[i]*o/n}return e},t.Index.prototype.toJSON=function(){var e={};return this._fields.forEach(function(t){e[t]=this.index[t].toJSON()},this),{version:t.version,fields:this._fields,ref:this._ref,documentStore:this.documentStore.toJSON(),index:e,pipeline:this.pipeline.toJSON()}},t.Index.prototype.use=function(e){var t=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);t.unshift(this),e.apply(this,t)},t.DocumentStore=function(e){this._save=null===e||void 0===e?!0:e,this.docs={},this.docInfo={},this.length=0},t.DocumentStore.load=function(e){var t=new this;return t.length=e.length,t.docs=e.docs,t.docInfo=e.docInfo,t._save=e.save,t},t.DocumentStore.prototype.isDocStored=function(){return this._save},t.DocumentStore.prototype.addDoc=function(t,n){this.hasDoc(t)||this.length++,this.docs[t]=this._save===!0?e(n):null},t.DocumentStore.prototype.getDoc=function(e){return this.hasDoc(e)===!1?null:this.docs[e]},t.DocumentStore.prototype.hasDoc=function(e){return e in this.docs},t.DocumentStore.prototype.removeDoc=function(e){this.hasDoc(e)&&(delete this.docs[e],delete this.docInfo[e],this.length--)},t.DocumentStore.prototype.addFieldLength=function(e,t,n){null!==e&&void 0!==e&&0!=this.hasDoc(e)&&(this.docInfo[e]||(this.docInfo[e]={}),this.docInfo[e][t]=n)},t.DocumentStore.prototype.updateFieldLength=function(e,t,n){null!==e&&void 0!==e&&0!=this.hasDoc(e)&&this.addFieldLength(e,t,n)},t.DocumentStore.prototype.getFieldLength=function(e,t){return null===e||void 0===e?0:e in this.docs&&t in this.docInfo[e]?this.docInfo[e][t]:0},t.DocumentStore.prototype.toJSON=function(){return{docs:this.docs,docInfo:this.docInfo,length:this.length,save:this._save}},t.stemmer=function(){var e={ational:"ate",tional:"tion",enci:"ence",anci:"ance",izer:"ize",bli:"ble",alli:"al",entli:"ent",eli:"e",ousli:"ous",ization:"ize",ation:"ate",ator:"ate",alism:"al",iveness:"ive",fulness:"ful",ousness:"ous",aliti:"al",iviti:"ive",biliti:"ble",logi:"log"},t={icate:"ic",ative:"",alize:"al",iciti:"ic",ical:"ic",ful:"",ness:""},n="[^aeiou]",i="[aeiouy]",o=n+"[^aeiouy]*",r=i+"[aeiou]*",s="^("+o+")?"+r+o,u="^("+o+")?"+r+o+"("+r+")?$",a="^("+o+")?"+r+o+r+o,l="^("+o+")?"+i,c=new RegExp(s),d=new RegExp(a),f=new RegExp(u),h=new RegExp(l),p=/^(.+?)(ss|i)es$/,v=/^(.+?)([^s])s$/,g=/^(.+?)eed$/,m=/^(.+?)(ed|ing)$/,y=/.$/,S=/(at|bl|iz)$/,x=new RegExp("([^aeiouylsz])\\1$"),w=new RegExp("^"+o+i+"[^aeiouwxy]$"),I=/^(.+?[^aeiou])y$/,b=/^(.+?)(ational|tional|enci|anci|izer|bli|alli|entli|eli|ousli|ization|ation|ator|alism|iveness|fulness|ousness|aliti|iviti|biliti|logi)$/,E=/^(.+?)(icate|ative|alize|iciti|ical|ful|ness)$/,D=/^(.+?)(al|ance|ence|er|ic|able|ible|ant|ement|ment|ent|ou|ism|ate|iti|ous|ive|ize)$/,F=/^(.+?)(s|t)(ion)$/,_=/^(.+?)e$/,P=/ll$/,k=new RegExp("^"+o+i+"[^aeiouwxy]$"),z=function(n){var i,o,r,s,u,a,l;if(n.length<3)return n;if(r=n.substr(0,1),"y"==r&&(n=r.toUpperCase()+n.substr(1)),s=p,u=v,s.test(n)?n=n.replace(s,"$1$2"):u.test(n)&&(n=n.replace(u,"$1$2")),s=g,u=m,s.test(n)){var z=s.exec(n);s=c,s.test(z[1])&&(s=y,n=n.replace(s,""))}else if(u.test(n)){var z=u.exec(n);i=z[1],u=h,u.test(i)&&(n=i,u=S,a=x,l=w,u.test(n)?n+="e":a.test(n)?(s=y,n=n.replace(s,"")):l.test(n)&&(n+="e"))}if(s=I,s.test(n)){var z=s.exec(n);i=z[1],n=i+"i"}if(s=b,s.test(n)){var z=s.exec(n);i=z[1],o=z[2],s=c,s.test(i)&&(n=i+e[o])}if(s=E,s.test(n)){var z=s.exec(n);i=z[1],o=z[2],s=c,s.test(i)&&(n=i+t[o])}if(s=D,u=F,s.test(n)){var z=s.exec(n);i=z[1],s=d,s.test(i)&&(n=i)}else if(u.test(n)){var z=u.exec(n);i=z[1]+z[2],u=d,u.test(i)&&(n=i)}if(s=_,s.test(n)){var z=s.exec(n);i=z[1],s=d,u=f,a=k,(s.test(i)||u.test(i)&&!a.test(i))&&(n=i)}return s=P,u=d,s.test(n)&&u.test(n)&&(s=y,n=n.replace(s,"")),"y"==r&&(n=r.toLowerCase()+n.substr(1)),n};return z}(),t.Pipeline.registerFunction(t.stemmer,"stemmer"),t.stopWordFilter=function(e){return e&&t.stopWordFilter.stopWords[e]!==!0?e:void 0},t.clearStopWords=function(){t.stopWordFilter.stopWords={}},t.addStopWords=function(e){null!=e&&Array.isArray(e)!==!1&&e.forEach(function(e){t.stopWordFilter.stopWords[e]=!0},this)},t.resetStopWords=function(){t.stopWordFilter.stopWords=t.defaultStopWords},t.defaultStopWords={"":!0,a:!0,able:!0,about:!0,across:!0,after:!0,all:!0,almost:!0,also:!0,am:!0,among:!0,an:!0,and:!0,any:!0,are:!0,as:!0,at:!0,be:!0,because:!0,been:!0,but:!0,by:!0,can:!0,cannot:!0,could:!0,dear:!0,did:!0,"do":!0,does:!0,either:!0,"else":!0,ever:!0,every:!0,"for":!0,from:!0,get:!0,got:!0,had:!0,has:!0,have:!0,he:!0,her:!0,hers:!0,him:!0,his:!0,how:!0,however:!0,i:!0,"if":!0,"in":!0,into:!0,is:!0,it:!0,its:!0,just:!0,least:!0,let:!0,like:!0,likely:!0,may:!0,me:!0,might:!0,most:!0,must:!0,my:!0,neither:!0,no:!0,nor:!0,not:!0,of:!0,off:!0,often:!0,on:!0,only:!0,or:!0,other:!0,our:!0,own:!0,rather:!0,said:!0,say:!0,says:!0,she:!0,should:!0,since:!0,so:!0,some:!0,than:!0,that:!0,the:!0,their:!0,them:!0,then:!0,there:!0,these:!0,they:!0,"this":!0,tis:!0,to:!0,too:!0,twas:!0,us:!0,wants:!0,was:!0,we:!0,were:!0,what:!0,when:!0,where:!0,which:!0,"while":!0,who:!0,whom:!0,why:!0,will:!0,"with":!0,would:!0,yet:!0,you:!0,your:!0},t.stopWordFilter.stopWords=t.defaultStopWords,t.Pipeline.registerFunction(t.stopWordFilter,"stopWordFilter"),t.trimmer=function(e){if(null===e||void 0===e)throw new Error("token should not be undefined");return e.replace(/^\W+/,"").replace(/\W+$/,"")},t.Pipeline.registerFunction(t.trimmer,"trimmer"),t.InvertedIndex=function(){this.root={docs:{},df:0}},t.InvertedIndex.load=function(e){var t=new this;return t.root=e.root,t},t.InvertedIndex.prototype.addToken=function(e,t,n){for(var n=n||this.root,i=0;i<=e.length-1;){var o=e[i];o in n||(n[o]={docs:{},df:0}),i+=1,n=n[o]}var r=t.ref;n.docs[r]?n.docs[r]={tf:t.tf}:(n.docs[r]={tf:t.tf},n.df+=1)},t.InvertedIndex.prototype.hasToken=function(e){if(!e)return!1;for(var t=this.root,n=0;n<e.length;n++){if(!t[e[n]])return!1;t=t[e[n]]}return!0},t.InvertedIndex.prototype.getNode=function(e){if(!e)return null;for(var t=this.root,n=0;n<e.length;n++){if(!t[e[n]])return null;t=t[e[n]]}return t},t.InvertedIndex.prototype.getDocs=function(e){var t=this.getNode(e);return null==t?{}:t.docs},t.InvertedIndex.prototype.getTermFrequency=function(e,t){var n=this.getNode(e);return null==n?0:t in n.docs?n.docs[t].tf:0},t.InvertedIndex.prototype.getDocFreq=function(e){var t=this.getNode(e);return null==t?0:t.df},t.InvertedIndex.prototype.removeToken=function(e,t){if(e){var n=this.getNode(e);null!=n&&t in n.docs&&(delete n.docs[t],n.df-=1)}},t.InvertedIndex.prototype.expandToken=function(e,t,n){if(null==e||""==e)return[];var t=t||[];if(void 0==n&&(n=this.getNode(e),null==n))return t;n.df>0&&t.push(e);for(var i in n)"docs"!==i&&"df"!==i&&this.expandToken(e+i,t,n[i]);return t},t.InvertedIndex.prototype.toJSON=function(){return{root:this.root}},t.Configuration=function(e,n){var e=e||"";if(void 0==n||null==n)throw new Error("fields should not be null");this.config={};var i;try{i=JSON.parse(e),this.buildUserConfig(i,n)}catch(o){t.utils.warn("user configuration parse failed, will use default configuration"),this.buildDefaultConfig(n)}},t.Configuration.prototype.buildDefaultConfig=function(e){this.reset(),e.forEach(function(e){this.config[e]={boost:1,bool:"OR",expand:!1}},this)},t.Configuration.prototype.buildUserConfig=function(e,n){var i="OR",o=!1;if(this.reset(),"bool"in e&&(i=e.bool||i),"expand"in e&&(o=e.expand||o),"fields"in e)for(var r in e.fields)if(n.indexOf(r)>-1){var s=e.fields[r],u=o;void 0!=s.expand&&(u=s.expand),this.config[r]={boost:s.boost||0===s.boost?s.boost:1,bool:s.bool||i,expand:u}}else t.utils.warn("field name in user configuration not found in index instance fields");else this.addAllFields2UserConfig(i,o,n)},t.Configuration.prototype.addAllFields2UserConfig=function(e,t,n){n.forEach(function(n){this.config[n]={boost:1,bool:e,expand:t}},this)},t.Configuration.prototype.get=function(){return this.config},t.Configuration.prototype.reset=function(){this.config={}},lunr.SortedSet=function(){this.length=0,this.elements=[]},lunr.SortedSet.load=function(e){var t=new this;return t.elements=e,t.length=e.length,t},lunr.SortedSet.prototype.add=function(){var e,t;for(e=0;e<arguments.length;e++)t=arguments[e],~this.indexOf(t)||this.elements.splice(this.locationFor(t),0,t);this.length=this.elements.length},lunr.SortedSet.prototype.toArray=function(){return this.elements.slice()},lunr.SortedSet.prototype.map=function(e,t){return this.elements.map(e,t)},lunr.SortedSet.prototype.forEach=function(e,t){return this.elements.forEach(e,t)},lunr.SortedSet.prototype.indexOf=function(e){for(var t=0,n=this.elements.length,i=n-t,o=t+Math.floor(i/2),r=this.elements[o];i>1;){if(r===e)return o;e>r&&(t=o),r>e&&(n=o),i=n-t,o=t+Math.floor(i/2),r=this.elements[o]}return r===e?o:-1},lunr.SortedSet.prototype.locationFor=function(e){for(var t=0,n=this.elements.length,i=n-t,o=t+Math.floor(i/2),r=this.elements[o];i>1;)e>r&&(t=o),r>e&&(n=o),i=n-t,o=t+Math.floor(i/2),r=this.elements[o];return r>e?o:e>r?o+1:void 0},lunr.SortedSet.prototype.intersect=function(e){for(var t=new lunr.SortedSet,n=0,i=0,o=this.length,r=e.length,s=this.elements,u=e.elements;;){if(n>o-1||i>r-1)break;s[n]!==u[i]?s[n]<u[i]?n++:s[n]>u[i]&&i++:(t.add(s[n]),n++,i++)}return t},lunr.SortedSet.prototype.clone=function(){var e=new lunr.SortedSet;return e.elements=this.toArray(),e.length=e.elements.length,e},lunr.SortedSet.prototype.union=function(e){var t,n,i;this.length>=e.length?(t=this,n=e):(t=e,n=this),i=t.clone();for(var o=0,r=n.toArray();o<r.length;o++)i.add(r[o]);return i},lunr.SortedSet.prototype.toJSON=function(){return this.toArray()},function(e,t){"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(t):"object"==typeof exports?module.exports=t():e.elasticlunr=t()}(this,function(){return t})}();
2022-06-19T15:22:18.3898514Z -    /** pdoc search index */const docs = [{"fullname": "my_pkg", "modulename": "my_pkg", "type": "module", "doc": "<p>Test documentation</p>\n"}, {"fullname": "my_pkg.test_fun", "modulename": "my_pkg", "qualname": "test_fun", "type": "function", "doc": "<p>My function.</p>\n", "signature": "()", "funcdef": "def"}, {"fullname": "my_pkg.experimental", "modulename": "my_pkg.experimental", "type": "module", "doc": "<p></p>\n"}, {"fullname": "my_pkg.__init__", "modulename": "my_pkg.__init__", "type": "module", "doc": "<p>Test documentation</p>\n"}, {"fullname": "my_pkg.__init__.test_fun", "modulename": "my_pkg.__init__", "qualname": "test_fun", "type": "function", "doc": "<p>My function.</p>\n", "signature": "()", "funcdef": "def"}, {"fullname": "my_pkg.experimental.__init__", "modulename": "my_pkg.experimental.__init__", "type": "module", "doc": "<p></p>\n"}, {"fullname": "setup", "modulename": "setup", "type": "module", "doc": "<p></p>\n"}, {"fullname": "test_testing", "modulename": "test_testing", "type": "module", "doc": "<p></p>\n"}, {"fullname": "test_testing.test_testing", "modulename": "test_testing", "qualname": "test_testing", "type": "function", "doc": "<p></p>\n", "signature": "()", "funcdef": "def"}];
2022-06-19T15:22:18.3908064Z +    /** pdoc search index */const docs = {"version": "0.9.5", "fields": ["qualname", "fullname", "annotation", "default_value", "signature", "bases", "doc"], "ref": "fullname", "documentStore": {"docs": {"my_pkg": {"fullname": "my_pkg", "modulename": "my_pkg", "type": "module", "doc": "<p>Test documentation</p>\n"}, "my_pkg.test_fun": {"fullname": "my_pkg.test_fun", "modulename": "my_pkg", "qualname": "test_fun", "type": "function", "doc": "<p>My function.</p>\n", "signature": "()", "funcdef": "def"}, "my_pkg.experimental": {"fullname": "my_pkg.experimental", "modulename": "my_pkg.experimental", "type": "module", "doc": "<p></p>\n"}, "my_pkg.__init__": {"fullname": "my_pkg.__init__", "modulename": "my_pkg.__init__", "type": "module", "doc": "<p>Test documentation</p>\n"}, "my_pkg.__init__.test_fun": {"fullname": "my_pkg.__init__.test_fun", "modulename": "my_pkg.__init__", "qualname": "test_fun", "type": "function", "doc": "<p>My function.</p>\n", "signature": "()", "funcdef": "def"}, "my_pkg.experimental.__init__": {"fullname": "my_pkg.experimental.__init__", "modulename": "my_pkg.experimental.__init__", "type": "module", "doc": "<p></p>\n"}, "setup": {"fullname": "setup", "modulename": "setup", "type": "module", "doc": "<p></p>\n"}, "test_testing": {"fullname": "test_testing", "modulename": "test_testing", "type": "module", "doc": "<p></p>\n"}, "test_testing.test_testing": {"fullname": "test_testing.test_testing", "modulename": "test_testing", "qualname": "test_testing", "type": "function", "doc": "<p></p>\n", "signature": "()", "funcdef": "def"}}, "docInfo": {"my_pkg": {"qualname": 0, "fullname": 2, "annotation": 0, "default_value": 0, "signature": 0, "bases": 0, "doc": 4}, "my_pkg.test_fun": {"qualname": 2, "fullname": 4, "annotation": 0, "default_value": 0, "signature": 2, "bases": 0, "doc": 5}, "my_pkg.experimental": {"qualname": 0, "fullname": 3, "annotation": 0, "default_value": 0, "signature": 0, "bases": 0, "doc": 3}, "my_pkg.__init__": {"qualname": 0, "fullname": 4, "annotation": 0, "default_value": 0, "signature": 0, "bases": 0, "doc": 4}, "my_pkg.__init__.test_fun": {"qualname": 2, "fullname": 5, "annotation": 0, "default_value": 0, "signature": 2, "bases": 0, "doc": 5}, "my_pkg.experimental.__init__": {"qualname": 0, "fullname": 5, "annotation": 0, "default_value": 0, "signature": 0, "bases": 0, "doc": 3}, "setup": {"qualname": 0, "fullname": 1, "annotation": 0, "default_value": 0, "signature": 0, "bases": 0, "doc": 3}, "test_testing": {"qualname": 0, "fullname": 2, "annotation": 0, "default_value": 0, "signature": 0, "bases": 0, "doc": 3}, "test_testing.test_testing": {"qualname": 2, "fullname": 4, "annotation": 0, "default_value": 0, "signature": 2, "bases": 0, "doc": 3}}, "length": 9, "save": true}, "index": {"qualname": {"root": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "t": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "e": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "s": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "t": {"docs": {"my_pkg.test_fun": {"tf": 1}, "my_pkg.__init__.test_fun": {"tf": 1}, "test_testing.test_testing": {"tf": 1}}, "df": 3, "i": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "n": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "g": {"docs": {"test_testing.test_testing": {"tf": 1}}, "df": 1}}}}}}}, "f": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "u": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "n": {"docs": {"my_pkg.test_fun": {"tf": 1}, "my_pkg.__init__.test_fun": {"tf": 1}}, "df": 2}}}}}, "fullname": {"root": {"docs": {"my_pkg.__init__": {"tf": 1}, "my_pkg.experimental.__init__": {"tf": 1}}, "df": 2, "l": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "i": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "e": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "s": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "e": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "l": {"docs": {"my_pkg": {"tf": 1}, "my_pkg.test_fun": {"tf": 1}, "my_pkg.experimental": {"tf": 1}, "my_pkg.__init__": {"tf": 1}, "my_pkg.__init__.test_fun": {"tf": 1}, "my_pkg.experimental.__init__": {"tf": 1}}, "df": 6}}}}}}, "i": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "n": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "t": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "e": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "r": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "n": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "a": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "l": {"docs": {"my_pkg": {"tf": 1}, "my_pkg.test_fun": {"tf": 1}, "my_pkg.experimental": {"tf": 1}, "my_pkg.__init__": {"tf": 1}, "my_pkg.__init__.test_fun": {"tf": 1}, "my_pkg.experimental.__init__": {"tf": 1}}, "df": 6}}}}}}, "i": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "t": {"docs": {"my_pkg.__init__": {"tf": 1}, "my_pkg.__init__.test_fun": {"tf": 1}, "my_pkg.experimental.__init__": {"tf": 1}}, "df": 3}}}}, "t": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "e": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "s": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "t": {"docs": {"my_pkg.test_fun": {"tf": 1}, "my_pkg.__init__.test_fun": {"tf": 1}, "test_testing": {"tf": 1}, "test_testing.test_testing": {"tf": 1.4142135623730951}}, "df": 4, "i": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "n": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "g": {"docs": {"test_testing": {"tf": 1}, "test_testing.test_testing": {"tf": 1.4142135623730951}}, "df": 2}}}}}}}, "f": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "u": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "n": {"docs": {"my_pkg.test_fun": {"tf": 1}, "my_pkg.__init__.test_fun": {"tf": 1}}, "df": 2}}}, "e": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "x": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "p": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "e": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "r": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "i": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "m": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "e": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "n": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "t": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "a": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "l": {"docs": {"my_pkg.experimental": {"tf": 1}, "my_pkg.experimental.__init__": {"tf": 1}}, "df": 2}}}}}}}}}}}}, "s": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "e": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "t": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "u": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "p": {"docs": {"setup": {"tf": 1}}, "df": 1}}}}}}}, "annotation": {"root": {"docs": {}, "df": 0}}, "default_value": {"root": {"docs": {}, "df": 0}}, "signature": {"root": {"docs": {"my_pkg.test_fun": {"tf": 1.4142135623730951}, "my_pkg.__init__.test_fun": {"tf": 1.4142135623730951}, "test_testing.test_testing": {"tf": 1.4142135623730951}}, "df": 3}}, "bases": {"root": {"docs": {}, "df": 0}}, "doc": {"root": {"docs": {"my_pkg": {"tf": 1.4142135623730951}, "my_pkg.test_fun": {"tf": 1.7320508075688772}, "my_pkg.experimental": {"tf": 1.7320508075688772}, "my_pkg.__init__": {"tf": 1.4142135623730951}, "my_pkg.__init__.test_fun": {"tf": 1.7320508075688772}, "my_pkg.experimental.__init__": {"tf": 1.7320508075688772}, "setup": {"tf": 1.7320508075688772}, "test_testing": {"tf": 1.7320508075688772}, "test_testing.test_testing": {"tf": 1.7320508075688772}}, "df": 9, "t": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "e": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "s": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "t": {"docs": {"my_pkg": {"tf": 1}, "my_pkg.__init__": {"tf": 1}}, "df": 2}}}}, "d": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "o": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "c": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "u": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "m": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "e": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "n": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "t": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "a": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "t": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "i": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "o": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "n": {"docs": {"my_pkg": {"tf": 1}, "my_pkg.__init__": {"tf": 1}}, "df": 2}}}}}}}}}}}}}, "m": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "y": {"docs": {"my_pkg.test_fun": {"tf": 1}, "my_pkg.__init__.test_fun": {"tf": 1}}, "df": 2}}, "f": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "u": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "n": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "c": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "t": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "i": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "o": {"docs": {}, "df": 0, "n": {"docs": {"my_pkg.test_fun": {"tf": 1}, "my_pkg.__init__.test_fun": {"tf": 1}}, "df": 2}}}}}}}}}}}, "pipeline": ["trimmer"], "_isPrebuiltIndex": true};
```

I use Pdoc v12.0.2 both locally and on GitHub, and nothing about my package's source code is different between the local and GitHub versions.

Comment: perhaps you have a different set of packages installed locally?  ideally pre-commit would manage the installation and you'd have a more repeatable setup (also generating docs as part of a pre-commit hook is probably a bad idea -- as is checking in the output but that's another story).  try recreating your environment locally and perhaps they will match?  also try `--show-diff-on-failure` to get a hint as to what is changing.  but without more information this is un-answerable and can only be guessed at

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Pre-commit does manage the installation through `pip install .[dev]`. The installed packages are identical online and in the local version, where I use a fresh virtual environment and likewise run `pip install .[dev]`.

Thanks for suggesting `--show-diff-on-failure`, I included the additional information in the original question.

Comment: P.S.: Sorry, of course it is not pre-commit itself that manages the installation of the packages, but the GitHub action.

Comment: `a` and `b` are git diff markers -- they aren't real directories -- they allow a patch applicator to differentiate.  the actual difference is just below that but you haven't included that

Comment: Thanks for educating me! I included the full diff in the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pdoc tries to precompile the search index if it can find Node.js on the machine it's running on. We unfortunately rely on JS here, see https://pdoc.dev/docs/pdoc/search.html. You may have that on one of the machines but not the other, which generates the difference.

If you are using GitHub pages, you don't have to keep the compiled docs in the repo: https://pdoc.dev/docs/pdoc.html#deploying-to-github-pages

Comment: Thanks a lot! Indeed, this is the explanation. On my local machine, I do not have Node.js installed, while it seems to be available for the GitHub Action.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Pdoc v12.0.2 creates the `search.js` file slightly differently depending on the operating system (I do not know about other versions). In my case, I ran Pdoc in the pre-commit locally on MacOS, while Pdoc ran on Ubuntu in the GitHub CI.

When I run Pdoc locally on Ubuntu as well, there is no difference between the local version and the GitHub version.